# laravel on vps: The main page shows the PHP code

Tags: laravel, vps

I'm pretty new to the whole issue of LARAVEL , and try to install it on a VPS server.

Probably something in my setup was not true that the main page of the site claims the INDEX.PHP and shows all the code ...

How do I overcome this problem ?

```
 http://82.199.155.111/
```

Comment: What kind of web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is fixed now. I'm guessing that you hadn't got PHP set up on the server?